# Create React Native app could not installed

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, create-react-app, npm-start

As we know Create React Native App is the easiest way to start building a new React Native application. But I tried to install this but I got failed.
I am using Node **v8.10.0** and npm **v4.2.0**.

Error Attached below.
I stucked here.
[image]

Final Error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Task Manager by `ctrl+alt+del`  and close all the node.js processes. Then rerun the command `create-react-native-app <yourname>`, this time try it with other name instead of "AwesomeProject".

Comment: No Process is running related to node. still same situation.

Comment: First try creating the app with some other name. If it doesn't work, Restart your computer and try again .

Comment: Use the CLI instead : npm install -g react-native-cli